# how to get relational table field in yii2 view?

Tags: php, yii2

I am want to get relational table field value in View,But the relational table maybe have not corresponding data.Can I use some method to replace the php code in Yii2 View?

```php
// $model->relationTable maybe is null
<?= isset($model->relationalTable)?$model->relationalTable->field:'' ?>
```

I hope `$model->relationalTable->field` can work when `$model->relationalTable` is null.I wantn't a lot of `if condition` in view.

Comment: You need to override main model of your table, if you are using crud generator, edit that  models related ur table name

Comment: You should always check if related record(s) exists. If you want to access certain field in the related record, you can create a method in the model class, perform check there and return the field value

Comment: @MichaelKrutikov Krutikov  I need to write getField() method in model for all relational table field?

Answer (score 0):

**example:**

in Model class:

```
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Customer::className(), ['id' => 'customer_id']);
}
```

**Use:**

```
$customers = Customer::find()
    ->joinWith('user')
    ->one();
```

**Access**:

```
$customers->user->id;
```

**See the documentation [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#relational-data)**

Comment: if $customers->user is null,$customers->user->id will have error

Comment: Note: For example, the **user** in `$customers->user->id` is equivalent to the `getUser()` method

Comment: i know,In my exmaple ```$customers->user``` maybe is null,if you use ```$customers->user->id``` ,you will get error message of ```Trying to get property of non-object```

Comment: **You must do the relational settings in the database**. If done properly relation in the database, this will not be possible to create a row from the **customer table** with the `customer _id` that is not the equivalent of the `ID` in the **user's table**.

Comment: Use   `->where(related.id is not null')`

Comment: can check `is_object()`

Comment: You can escape error with `@$customers->user->id` so if the user is null, it will return null instead of throwing an error

Comment: Using  `@`  is wrong. Does not handle the error, but hides it. It's best to check with `is_object`  or ... (for $customers->user)

Comment: PHP handles expressions using an @ in a less performant way than expressions without an @.  Secondly, the error control operator completely swallows the error.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are having issue in view page, I am assuming your question is related to displaying data in DetailView widget. 
Below is the code sample:

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'vehicle_id',
        [
            'attribute' => 'maker',
            'label' => 'Maker Details',
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'user_id',
            'label' => 'Assigned To',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function ($model) {
                $value =  isset($model->user->name) ? $model->user->name : NULL;
                return $value;
            }, 
        ],
    ],
]) ?>
```

If you have implemented ACL or RBAC, you can further refine your code as shown below:

```
        [
            'attribute' => 'user_id',
            'label' => 'Assigned To',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function ($model) {
                $value = isset($model->user->name) ? $model->user->name : NULL;
                $id = isset($model->user_id) ? $model->user_id : NULL;
                if($value && $id){
                    if(Yii::$app->user->can('user/view')){
                       $value = Html::a($value, ['user/view', 'id' => $id], ['class' => '']);
                    }
                }
                return $value;
            }, 
        ],
```

Hope this help. Or give some more information/code to help understand your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to simplify this code, you can use `??` operator:

```
<?= $model->relationalTable->field ?? '' ?>
```

If you need to encode it:

```
<?= Html::encode($model->relationalTable->field ?? '') ?>
```

Alternatively you may create helper method, which will do such check for you, and then call it in this way:

```
<?= $model->getRelationalTableField() ?>
```

But if you can do this, probably the best option is to configure foreign key constraint for related record at DB level, so database will ensure that related record always exist - you don't need any checks then.